# Is there a public website that converts swagger json to PDF for HTML?

Tags: pdf, swagger

Has anyone made where, where you just enter your swagger URL .../swagger/docs/v1
and then the website converts it to HTML, pdf, doc or whatever in a nice readable format?  I'd think that site would get a lot of traffic (hint)

I know there are some things on github you can download that will convert things, but I'd think someone has made a public site so I can save some time.

Comment: Related: [Generate PDF from Swagger API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30217910/113116)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one: [swagger2html](https://github.com/chenjianjx/swagger2html) .

The document generated by swagger-codegen is indeed not readable. This project makes a neat appearance(bootstrap css) and shows the fields in the request/response models in a straightforward manner.

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use this website : [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io/)
Copy your swagger file and in the menu, select 'Generate Client' -> 'HTML' (or Dynamic HTML')

You can also use [Swagger Code Generator](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) if you want to add this step in an automatic build flow.

Comment: That generate client doesn't look so nice thought

Comment: html2 looks just perfect (Generate Client -> html2), further you can just print it to PDF file if you want to make it more friendly in terms of sharing through mails to your API consumers.

Comment: If this ever worked, it doesn't any longer. The console now simply records a `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` error. `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ...`