# How to print a Swagger / OpenAPI Spec beautiful

Tags: pdf, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

we are new in Swagger / Open API v2.0. Our first API spec is ready. Now we have problems to print out the Spec beautiful. Export from UI are not useful for print. And Google don't help. How do you do that? Knows anyone some good tools?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate PDF from Swagger API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217910/generate-pdf-from-swagger-api-documentation)

Answer (score 3):

For a printed / PDF output, you may want to look at something like [swagger2markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup), you can then convert the output asciidoc to PDF etc with [asciidoctorj](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctorj).