# How can i convert a swagger.yaml file into a pdf?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have tried some tools, these produce good results regarding a documentation, but a similar graphic view as the swagger ui I have not found. 
Is there a tool to convert the swagger api def into a similiar looking pdf?

tools i tried from the docker hub:

[swagger2pdf](https://hub.docker.com/r/tozny/swagger2pdf/)

**Iam looking for a pdf generator with a smiliar graphic view as the swagger UI.** A simple pdf conversation is possible with swagger2pdf as shown in link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate PDF from Swagger API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217910/generate-pdf-from-swagger-api-documentation)