# Convert Swagger JSON to AsciiDoc markdown

Tags: swagger, asciidoc

I'm trying to import Swagger JSON into AsciiDoc. To do that I'm trying to convert the Swagger JSON into markdown that can be read by AsciiDoc. I can't figure out how to do it. I've read that I will likely need to use [swagger2markup](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup/tree/master/src/main/java/io/github/swagger2markup). However, not being a Java programmer it's unclear how to use this. I got some clues from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217910/generate-pdf-from-swagger-api-documentation) but I can't get very far. It involves using J Unit and I don't know what to do with that and all that is required. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Comment: Make it [M.C.V.E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: It doesn't sound like an mvce situation to me. She's trying to figure out how to put some pieces together, I think.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out how to put this process together. All I have to go on, really, is the extended response from Aman Mohammed, but there is not enough detail for me to take action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217910/generate-pdf-from-swagger-api-documentation

Comment: Try this blog post: https://jaxenter.de/restful-apis-dokumentieren-52052

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from a coworker on how to convert the my Swagger JSON to AsciiDoc markdown. The more complex instructions [here](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup/tree/master/src/main/java/io/github/swagger2markup) were not what I needed. The CLI instructions [here](https://github.com/Swagger2Markup/swagger2markup-cli) were. The simpler conversion process using the CLI as opposed to integrating Swagger2Markdown into a Java app were ideal.